# How to automatically cross populate collections with Mongoose and MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Situation:
I have a simple database consisting of 3 collections: users, runs, orders.
orders contain runs ~orderItems~, and users can purchase multiple runs at one time.

My main question:
Is it possible, when I update my `order.isPaid === true`, to automatically cross populate my collections using MongoDB. I would like to populate the same fields I am currently passing.

Below is the actual behavior:

```
order.orderItems = [{runObj}]
user.runs = [{runId}]
run.users = [{userObj}]
```

```
const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    orderItems: [
      {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        location: { type: String, required: true },
        date: { type: String, required: true },
        price: { type: Number, required: true },
        run: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          required: true,
          ref: "Run",
        },
      },
    ],
})

const runSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    users: [
      {
        userId: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          required: true,
          ref: "User",
        },
        username: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        profilePhoto: {
          type: String,
        },
      },
    ]
})

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    runs: [
      {
        runId: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          required: true,
          ref: "Run",
        },
      },
    ],
})
```

This below functionality works, but I want a better understanding of what is happening with my Schema/Models and refs.

On successful checkout on Stripe, during the same request and trip to the database.

1. Update created order ( `order.isPaid === true` )
2. Asynchronously call updateRunsAndUser(orderItems, userId)

   ```
   const updateRunsAndUser = async (orderItems, userId) => {
     const user = await User.findById(userId);

     for (let i = 0; i < orderItems.length; i++) {
       const item = orderItems[i];
       const run = await Run.findById(item.run);
       const runId = run._id;
       user.runs.push({ runId });

       run.users.push({
         userId,
         username: user.username,
         profilePhoto: user.profilePhoto,
       });
       await user.save();
       await run.save();
     }
   };
   ```
3. Add User to each Run in the order aka the Order.orderItems, using userId param and iterating through orderItems
4. redirect to `/` with success message, `order.isPaid == true`, user is added to run, run contains user as well.

Resulting Behavior: (eliminating properties on objects that are irrelevant):

```
sampleOrderAfterCheckout = {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5fa43b8624b3da0a5d02797d" },
    "orderItems": [
        {
            "_id": { "$oid": "5fa43b8624b3da0a5d02797e" },
            "run": { "$oid": "5fa436adf1047f07cc1af8d1" },
            "name": "Wednesday Night Run",
            "price": 10,
            "location": "The Post",
            "date": "11-04-2020"
        }
    ],
}

sampleRunAfterCheckout = {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5fa436adf1047f07cc1af8d1" },
    "users": [
        {
        "_id": { "$oid": "5fa43b9124b3da0a5d027980" },
        "userId": { "$oid": "5fa436adf1047f07cc1af8cd" },
        "username": "merkyoass"
        },
    ],
}

sampleUserAfterCheckout = {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5fa436adf1047f07cc1af8cd" },
    "isAdmin": true,
    "username": "merkyoass",
    "runs": [
        {
            "_id": { "$oid": "5fa43b9124b3da0a5d02797f" },
            "runId": { "$oid": "5fa436adf1047f07cc1af8d1" }
        }
    ],
}
```

runId found in all 3 documents,
1. orderObj,
`Order.orderItems[0].run === 5fa436adf1047f07cc1af8d1`
2. runObj,
`run._id === 5fa436adf1047f07cc1af8d1`
3. userObj,
`user.runs[0].runId === 5fa436adf1047f07cc1af8d1`

One of my main questions, is where is `Order.orderItems[0]._id` and `users.runs[0]._id` coming
from? They cannot be found in any other Collection

```
Order.orderItems = [
                {
                    "_id": { "$oid": "5fa43b8624b3da0a5d02797e" }, 
                    "run": { "$oid": "5fa436adf1047f07cc1af8d1" },
                }
            ]
    
User.runs = [
                {
                    "_id": { "$oid": "5fa43b9124b3da0a5d02797f" }, 
                    "runId": { "$oid": "5fa436adf1047f07cc1af8d1" }
                }
            ]
```